# Use sed in loop to search and replace for multiple files

Tags: perl, sed

I have list of files as below:

```
RF1.lib
RF2.lib
RF3.lib 
etc..
```

In each of the `*.lib` files I have to replace this string `vlib` with the name of the file like `RF1`, `RF2` etc.

I am using the `sed` command to search and replace the string as below:

```
sed -i -e 's/vlib/RF1/g' RF1.lib

sed -i -e 's/vlib/RF2/g' RF2.lib
```

But I am having to do this multiple times to search and replace for every file.

Is there a way I can open the files in a loop and use the `sed` command to do the replacement in each file?

Comment: The replacement is filename dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Perl script which will replace the string in each file with filename:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $file (glob "/path/to/dir/*.lib") #get all the '.lib' files from dir
{
    my ($filename) = $file =~ m/([^\/]+)\.lib$/; #get the filename
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
    my @data = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    foreach my $line (@data)
    {   
        $line =~ s/\bvlib\b/$filename/g; #replace string with filename
    }
    #modify the file
    open my $fhw, ">", $file or die "Couldn't modify file: $!";
    print $fhw @data;
    close $fhw;
}
```

**Edit:** As *Borodin* suggested in comment, reading whole file into scalar:

```
foreach my $file (glob "/path/to/dir/*.lib")  #get all the '.lib' files from dir
{
    my ($filename) = $file =~ m/([^\/]+)\.lib$/;  #get the filename

    #read whole file in a scalar
    my $data = do {
        local $/ = undef;
        open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
        <$fh>;
    };
    $data =~ s/\bvlib\b/$filename/g;  #replace string with filename

    #modify the file
    open my $fhw, ">", $file or die "Couldn't modify file: $!";
    print $fhw $data;
    close $fhw;
}
```

Comment: Could you not just open `$file` for output?

Comment: There's really no need to keep two copies of the data from the file. You may as well just modify `@data` in-place. And while we're at it, keeping the data in an array forces you to use a loop to modify it. If you read the whole file into a scalar then you can make the changes in a single operation. It's also probably best to use a pattern of `\bvlib\b` to avoid chnaging the ends of something like `navlib`

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can say:

```
for f1 in RF*.lib: do
    j=`basemame $f1 .lib`
    sed -i -e "s/vlib/$j/g" $f1
 done
```

Comment: Hi Sureshhvv, I am new to perl. When I use this in a perl script, I get the error 'Missing $ on loop variable at  line 3' .Please could you let me know what is wrong?

Comment: That's because it's not a perl script, it's shell.

Comment: Yes. As @Sobrique says, this is just a shell script that can be run from command line

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|(.*)\.*|sed -i "s/vlib/\1/g" &|e' fileOfFiles
```

This evaluates a sed command for each of the files in the file containing files. If you prefer the output of the command can be piped into a shell for the same effect, like so:

```
sed -r 's|(.*)\.*|sed -i "s/vlib/\1/g" &|' fileOfFiles | sh
```

Comment: Thanks Potong. this works, but instead of replacing 'vlib' with 'RF1', it replaces vlib with 'RF1.lib' etc..